# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ... to smallint (but there is no nvarchar!)

Tags: sql

Probably a dumb question.

When I run the query

```
DELETE FROM "ITEM"
WHERE "COUNIDAD" = '130' AND "COINGRES" = 1 AND "ITEM" = '0002' AND "COCAJA" = '001'
```

It returns the error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '130|' to data type smallint.
```

But the is no '130|' in my query as you can see.

What is happening?

Edit: 
    `COUNIDAD nvarchar(3), COINGRES smallint, ITEM nvarchar (5), COCAJA nvarchar(3)`

just in case

Edit 2:

Is specially weird since the query:

```
SELECT * FROM "ITEM" 
WHERE "COUNIDAD" = '130' AND "COINGRES" = 1 AND "ITEM" = '0002' AND "COCAJA" = '001'
```

Returns the row I want to delete

Edit 3:

Update doesn't work either :/

Comment: Is there a trigger on the `"Item"` for updates and/or deletes? Given that your `SELECT` statement works, it sounds like there's something automagically happening.

Comment: OMG I cannot believe it, is true, there was 2 triggers in the database. I deleted them and the process worked. I didn't work here since the beggining so I couldn't know. You are a life saver thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jason Whitish mention, there was 2 triggers already created in the database (I didn't know pls no hate :S).
I deleted them and the process worked.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query logic, this could only occur if `COINGRES` were really a string.  You can fix the problem by having the comparison be a string:

```
DELETE FROM "ITEM"
WHERE "COUNIDAD" = '130' AND "COINGRES" = '1' AND "ITEM" = '0002' AND "COCAJA" = '001';
```

Comment: DELETE FROM "ITEM"WHERE "COUNIDAD" = '130' AND "COINGRES" = '1' AND "ITEM" = '0002' AND "COCAJA" = '001' Returns the same error. COINGRES was a string but I converted the field to smallint for other reasons.